# Couldn't match expected type `Maybe (String, Int, String)' with actual type `([Char], t0, [Char])'

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am testing examples in the [Haskell Tutorial for C Programmers (Part 2)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_Tutorial_for_C_Programmers#Part_II:_Functions.2C_But_Really_a_Sidetrack_to_Types) and am having a bit of trouble with this one....

```
showPet :: Maybe (String, Int, String) -> String
showPet Nothing     = "none"
showPet (Just (name, age, species)) = "a " ++ species ++ " named " ++ name ++ ", aged " ++ (show age)
```

While it compiles, invoking it with

```
showPet ("cat",5,"felix")
```

results in

```
<interactive>:131:9:
Couldn't match expected type `Maybe (String, Int, String)'
            with actual type `([Char], t0, [Char])'
In the first argument of `showPet', namely `("cat", 5, "felix")'
In the expression: showPet ("cat", 5, "felix")
In an equation for `it': it = showPet ("cat", 5, "felix")
```

Am I calling it incorrectly or is it a change in Haskell that renders this in need of a change (I have found a few)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You specified in the type of `showPet`, that your first parameter should be of type `showPet :: Maybe (String, Int, String)`, but you only supplied a `(String, Int, String)`

You'll need to "wrap" your value in some `Maybe` value to make this work.  For maybes this is easy because if you have a value, you'll always just use `Just` (`Just`'s type is `a -> Maybe a`)

The final working result is, `showPet (Just ("cat",5,"felix"))`

Answer (score 9):

The type error is telling you that `showPet` expects `Maybe something`, but you are passing it `something`.

In Haskell the `Maybe` type is an explicit wrapper that indicates in the type system that a value might not be present. At runtime  absence is signified by the `Nothing` value, and the presence of the value requires the `Just` wrapper.

So you need to call `showPet` with `showPet (Just ("cat",5,"felix"))`.

Note that the way you call `showPet` closely matches its definition - the syntax for the call matches up with the syntax for the `showPet (Just ...` line.